# How to find std dev partitioned or grouped data using pyspark dataframe?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Code:

```
w = Window().partitionBy("ticker").orderBy("date")
x = s_df.withColumn("daily_return", (col("close") - lag("close", 1).over(w)) / lag("close", 1).over(w))
```

What s_df looks like:

```
+----------+------+------+------+------+--------+------+
|      date|  open|  high|   low| close|  volume|ticker|
+----------+------+------+------+------+--------+------+
|2016-11-02| 111.4|112.35|111.23|111.59|28331709|  AAPL|
|2016-11-01|113.46|113.77|110.53|111.49|43825812|  AAPL|
|2016-10-31|113.65|114.23| 113.2|113.54|26419398|  AAPL|
+----------+------+------+------+------+--------+------+
```

What X looks like then:

```
+----------+--------------------+
|      date|   avg(daily_return)|
+----------+--------------------+
|2015-12-28|0.004124786535090563|
|2015-11-20|0.006992226387807268|
|2015-12-29| 0.01730500286123971|
```

I want to find the standard deviation of avg(daily_return) for every group of tickers.

What I tried:

```
x.agg(stddev("avg(daily_return)")).over(w)
```

I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'over'
```

Is what I'm trying to do not possible or is there another way to do it?

[image]

Comment: how did you arrive at the  `avg(daily_return)` column, because your code for `x` produces something else.

Comment: can't you just do `groupBy("date","ticker").agg(..)` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128470/discussion-between-pr338-and-mtoto).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ticker` is a different dimension than `data` so you cannot have these two aggregated together. You can:

```
s_df_w_daily_rets = s_df.withColumn("daily_return", 
    (col("close") - lag("close", 1).over(w)) / lag("close", 1).over(w))

s_df_w_daily_rets.groupBy("date").agg(avg("daily_return"))
s_df_w_daily_rets.groupBy("ticker").agg(stddev("daily_return"))
```

`groupBy("date","ticker").agg(..)`  doesn't make sense because you have only one ticker `date`, `ticker` group and standard deviation will be undefined.

Answer (score 2):

You can

```
x.groupBy("A").agg(stddev("D"))
```

Comment: This gives an error AnalysisException: u"cannot resolve 'A' given input columns: [B, avg(E)];"